# How to find all GOOGLETRANSLATE formulas executed or not from external means?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-translate

I am developing a data processing app using Google Sheets and its API as backend .

In that I will upload all datas as arrays with GOOGLETRANSLATE via batchUpdate API like below

```
[hello_word,"Hello World",=GOOGLETRANSLATE("Hello World","en","es"),=GOOGLETRANSLATE("Hello World","en","fr"),=GOOGLETRANSLATE("Hello World","en","ar")]

[good_morning,"Good morning ",=GOOGLETRANSLATE("Good morning ","en","es"),=GOOGLETRANSLATE("Good morning ","en","fr"),=GOOGLETRANSLATE("Good morning ","en","ar")]

// 1000 keys ....
```

Now my problem is ,

Since there are more than 3000 cells to be translated , it take some time .

Meanwhile , the cells showing "Loading..." message until translations finished

Now my need is , I need some ways to find whether all of 3000+ cells are translated from outside , that is something like , executing a script in Google Sheet(stored in apps script) from a REST API such as Google Sheets API .

**What I tried** 
First I search Stackoverflow and got a script and executed it manually in console with some success.

```
function searchText() {
  var findText = "Loading...";

var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var CurrSheet = sheet.getSheetByName('strings');
var SHTvalues = CurrSheet.createTextFinder(findText).findAll();
var result = SHTvalues.map(r => ({row: r.getRow(), col: r.getColumn()}));
//Logger.log(result);
if (result.length > 0) {
  Logger.log('still trlansating ');
}
else Logger.log('translated ');
}
```

The above script works good , but there is a catch.

I am using the search word as 'Loading...'to find in progress cells and it's working

But if any cell contains a user data exactly as 'Loading...', then I am getting false positives !!! , that is translating still in progress !!

So I altered the formula like this : `=IFERROR(GOOGLETRANSLATE(A1,"en","es"),"TRANS_PRG")`

Then used "TRANS_PRG" as searchText and that issue resolved , but also if the translating failed or formula error , it's still having TRANS_PRG only(can't find the difference between loading error and formula error )

So I also need a permanent  solution to know the status for formulas from an external end ?

Please guide me

Comment: This is a **[Duplicate Post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/162397)**.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pushing data and *translation formulas* to a spreadsheet, obtain translations through the [Language Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language), and push the data and the *translated text* to the spreadsheet.